# What's happening in the freezers?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, entropy

A glass of water cools down when kept in a freezer. So the temperature of the water goes down and so the entropy decreases. But we know
that the universe's entropy is increasing. So what's happening in the freezer?

Comment: The entropy of the surroundings (the freezer itself, the air being heated etc.) increases more than the entropy of the freezer content decreases

Answer (score 1):

The temperature and the entropy of the water in the freezer decreases because heat is transported by the refrigerator to the outside. Therefore the entropy of the water decreases at the expense of an entropy increase outside the refrigerator. The total entropy refrigerator plus environment ("world") still increases.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you understand the difference between the inside of a freezer and the universe. More generally the second law statement is not a statement about the universe but of an isolated system (maybe the universe is isolated maybe not). For an isolated system energy is fixed and according to the second law entropy increases. Your freezer is not isolated. The cooling system gets energy (from burning coal or hopefully renewable) and this energy is used to extract energy from the glass of water. If you take the full system of refrigerator+earth+sun then the entropy is still going up.